# Barndoor on protruded wall

Tags: doors, renovation, barn

I am installing a barn door on a doorway that is protruded from the surrounding wall ~3 1/2".  The surrounding wall needs to support the door track so I need a way to bridge the 3 1/2" gap between the track header and the wall. I was planning to attach a 4x4 horizontally on the wall and attach the track to that.  Is there a better way?

I am also going to trim the door to match the 5/8" wide floor trim.  The trim will extend horizontally across the top of the doorway and over the 4x4. The trim is MDF, can I anchor the track into the MDF or do I need a hardwood header there?[image]

Comment: Using a 4x4 seems like a good way. Find one that isn't treated with chemicals for exterior use (if you can.) Doubled 2x4s might end up being easier for you. Rather that anchoring to the MDF, go through the MDF to the studs behind it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The 4x4 fir out of the non protruding area sounds like a good idea. It might be difficult to properly fasten it to the wall. Fastening it into the wall studs would be necessary. Perhaps some good toe screws (angled screws) from the top and bottom or a countersunk lag into the wall studs.

The trim piece of mdf can work as long as your door hanger rail hardware is fastened through that and into the solid wood behind it (the door header beam and your added 4x4).

Comment: 4-1/2" or 5" structural screws would be a good option for hanging the 4x4". A 4x4 is 3.5" actual, leaving 1 to 1-1/2" of screw going into the actual stud behind. You don't want more because you risk hitting wiring or plumbing that might be running through the studs. 2 screws per stud may seem a bit overkill, but should provide a very secure hold for the moving door, and better than it falling off.

Comment: I have some [HeadLok](https://www.fastenmaster.com/products/headlok) screws, I forget what length.  Is that good enough for securing the 4x4 to studs?  I also just installed a shower on the other side of the wall so I sure there is no plumbing or electric where this needs to go.  Should have put some blocking in while the wall was open but that ship has sailed.

Comment: It may be too late, @CoryS., but I believe your HeadLok screws should suffice. Also, if you're 100% certain there's nothing running through the studs, feel free to use longer screws, it can't hurt. Additionally, to ensure that this assembly doesn't come down on anyone, opening the wall (again) to install blocking wouldn't hurt. It's more work now, but safer in the long run and less work than fixing it after you (potentially) get out of the hospital.